# Can't run line command with AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Anyone why my parameters are not active please ?
thanks

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\rFactor\rFactor Dedicated.exe" "+oneclick +profile "serveur01""
```

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey doesn't need quotes for the program - it is not the same as batch scripting.

If your program requires quotes for the commandline parameter, then you include quotes.

But you don't have any spaces in the parameters, so you don't need any quotes at all.

```
Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\rFactor\rFactor Dedicated.exe +oneclick +profile serveur01
```